# issue with date() function. Need it to calculate from the first of the month

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, So I have this code.

```
        else if($_POST['sdate'] == 'this month')
                {


                        $startdate = date("m/d/y");
                        $newdate = Datetime::createFromFormat("m/d/y",$startdate);
                        $dpicker = $newdate->format("Y-m-d");
                        echo $dpicker;

                        $enddates = date("m/d/y");
                        $newEdate = Datetime::createFromFormat("m/d/y",$enddates);
                        $newEdate->modify('-20 day');
                        $edpicker = $newEdate->format("Y-m-d");
                        echo $edpicker;



                        $thdate = $dpicker;
                        $thdates = $edpicker;
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE loggedtime BETWEEN :times AND :time";
                        $q=$con->prepare($sql);
                        $q->bindparam(":time", $thdate);
                        $q->bindparam(":times", $thdates);
                        $q->execute();
                        while($data=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                        {
                            echo $data['customer'];
                        }

                }
```

So right now `$edpicker` is set to go back 20 days from today... I would like it to calculate that today is the 7th, so only go back 7 days.. I want that variable to always go back to the first of the month. So if today was the 18th.. It would go back 18 days.

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$firstDayOfMonth = new \DateTime('first day of this month');`

Comment: If you need `$edpicker` to always be the first day of the month, just write:  

`$edpicker= new \DateTime('first day of this month');`

Comment: How would I change it to first day of the week?>

Comment: Depending on what you consider as the first day of the week, the relative string format would be `"sunday this week"`. If you start your week on a Monday, substitute Sunday with Monday.

More information on PHP relative formats can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Comment: LAst question I promise, How would you tell it today? Just DateTime('today'); I will accept this now, Thanks again!

Comment: Everytime I use 'today' It does not display anything. All of the other ones work though.

Comment: Just simply creating a `DateTime` object with nothing in its constructor will assume "today" by default. So just call `new DateTime();`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5.3, you can use 'first day of this month'.
i.e:

```
$edpicker = new DateTime('first day of this month');
```

Otherwise, if you're using less than PHP 5.3, you can use

```
("m/01/y", $enddates)
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. Would that work the same for weeks though? $edpicker = new DateTime(first day of this week);? I did that and it still goes to the first... How would I do weeks? and are weeks counted mon-fri?

Comment: You can use `new DateTime('monday this week')`